# Starting an activity from an independent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am a beginner to Android development and I use kotlin. I followed a tutorial for splash and onboarding screens called "ViewPager2 with Navigation Component". Each screen is a fragment and after the onboarding screens, I end up at the HomeFragment and not the MainActivity. However, I am not familiar with the fragments.

Now, I want to create some other screens, activities, but cannot. I think that is because the home fragment is not a child of an activity. Here is my navigation graph:

[Navigation graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLAKY.png)

The codes for the HomeFragment is as below:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

}


fun toNextAct(view: View) {
   /* 
val intent = Intent(Context,NextActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)*/
}
}
```

I wanted to start an activity using a button with onClick function *toNextAct()* as above. Or, at least I want to go to the MainActivity somehow because it is not used. How can I fix the problem?

Edit1: There is a NavHostFragment inside the activity_main.xml but MainActivity is not the parent of the HomeFragment.

Edit2 regarding to comments: Here is my activity_main.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The HomeFragment's .xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="191dp"
        android:text="myButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The MainActivity.kt file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportActionBar?.hide()
        

    }

}
```

Comment: val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), NextActivity::class.java)
requireActivity().startActivity(intent)

Comment: Hi, when I click the button, the app crashes. I got the following error: _java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method toNextAct(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'myButton'_

Comment: myButton is placed inside fragment_home?

Comment: Yes, correct. Inside activity_main I have:

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout                                          ...(lines related to the cons. layout)..                                      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>'

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(activity, ActivityMain::class.java)
activity?.startActivity(intent)
```

here activity context is directory available to you in fragment only (you can simply copy paste and use this code)

Comment: Hi, the studio gives the following error and app cannot be opened: _Unresolved reference: ActivityMain_

Comment: that is going to be your activity (the one where you wish to navigate to)... replace `ActivityMain` with your activity name where you wish to navigate to

Comment: The other activity was named NextActivity so I wrote ActivityNext but get the same error. It is written in red again.

Comment: no no.. you have to write NextActivity only... I usually name my activities as such... just use `NextActivity::class.java`

Comment: Okay, I wrote 
'val intent = Intent(activity,NextActivity::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(intent)'
The app is opened now but when I click the button it crashes...

I get this error: _Could not find method toNextAct(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'myButton'_

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing in XML... can you please update your question and add the XML also

Comment: Hi, I edited the question, can you please take a look? Thank you.